Understand the way the package google.oauth2.id_token module need to be imported in recent release
I am using module-google.oauth2.id_token since some time and I was doing the import in the following way which is not working anymore:
>>> import google.auth
>>> google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'google.auth.transport' has no attribute 'requests'. Did you mean: 'Request'?

I am using now python 3.11.9 with google-auth 2.29.0. Following the new way written in the documentation and it works fine
>>> from google.auth.transport import requests
>>> requests.Request()
<google.auth.transport.requests.Request object at 0x74c740cd4a50>
>>> google.auth.__version__
'2.29.0'

My questions, which is a beginner python question, is why do I need to use the new way to important the package since the full path is identical and how can I detect such things ? (I guess it is related how the python module is build)
